# Oracle Apex 22 Problem with Label Button, Label Items, Float Menu

Tags: oracle-apex

In the Oracle Apex 22 version, the button labels, items, are not being displayed correctly. The same goes for the floating menu options, change the labels. I can't find the solution to this problem. At first, I thought it was the Universal - 42 theme, I downloaded it from another application but I couldn't fix the problem. When I check in the Apex Development environment, it works fine.

[Problem Label Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn68u.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem that I report is reflected in the link that I indicated in the question. By opening this link you can see the problem I am reporting. thank you ( Problem Label Items)